# Python - Find a particular line in a .csv file and replace it with new line

Tags: python, csv, ssh, sftp

Hopefully someone here will be able to help me as I am stuck.

I have three Raspberry Pi's in homes in three different cities. Every hour they check the temperature and humidity in the home and then connect to my local Raspberry Pi and record the temperature and humidity in a .csv file along with the date and time.  The resulting file appears as (the first two values in each line will always be the same):

```
Philadelphia, kitchen, 67.3, 40.2, 03/05/2022, 15:30:33
Miami, kitchen, 75.3, 50.2, 03/05/2022, 15:45:37
Dayton, basement, 63.1, 45.3, 03/05/2022, 15:22:30
Dayton, den, 63.7, 44.3, 03/05/2022, 15:22:30
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to find one particular line and replace it when the new values are uploaded.  For example, I need to change line 3 to:

```
Dayton, basement, 64.8, 45.5, 03/05/2022, 16:22:35
```

I am successfully  writing the values to the file using SSH with public and private keys:

```
temp = ("Dayton, " + "basement, " + temp + ", " + humidity + ", " + date + ", " + time)
def put_file(machinename, port, username):
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()
  ssh.connect(machinename, port, username=username)
  sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
  f = sftp.open('/home/PiSix/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-MyTemp/Data/Temps.csv', 'w')
  f.write(temp)
  f.close()

put_file('mydomain.ddns.net', port, 'PiSix')
```

Anyone have the answer that I am seeking?

Comment: Before we jump into the solution, is there a chance that these rasps wake up to write at this Temps.csv file at the same time?

Comment: Also, you want written on this csv file only the latest measurement, that's why you want to replace a given line for another (newer) line?

Comment: No, they are staggered in their times.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to want a single file? And most specifically, is there a reason for it to be a .csv?

Comment: Yes, I want the existing line to be deleted and the new matching  location line inserted in its place

Comment: Don't you agree with me that a separate file for each location would solve your problem?

Comment: Would a json file be just as good?

Comment: That's a good solution too, @JonSG

Comment: I agree with @GabrielPellegrino that you might want to guard against whatever might happen with concurrent requests from the remotes. We don't know how your api is implemented but maybe take a look at `treading.Lock()`

Comment: If you’re asking how to open and edit a master CSV from a remote sensor, that’s the wrong idea. Have each sensor write to its own log and then periodically, or whenever you care to look, take the last line from each log.